# Responsive - sadly not working

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

So, I have 2 sites on the first site I have it set up almost exactly the same way as the 2nd site but one menu is responsive and the other is not.

***WORKS = https://21divine.com

***DOES NOT WORK = https://theord.com

I am so confused. Here is my code for the non-working site.

```
<!-- ==============Header================= -->
<header class="site-header" role="banner">
```

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>


                </div><!-- navbar-header -->

                <!-- If the menu (WP admin area) is not set, then the "menu_class" is applied to "container". In other words, it overwrites the "container_class". Ref: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_nav_menu-menu_class-usage-bug?replies=4 -->

                <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(

                        'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                        'container'         => 'nav',
                        'container_class'   => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                        'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav navbar-left'

                    ) );
                ?>

            </div><!-- container -->

        </div><!-- navbar -->

    </div><!-- navbar-wrapper -->

</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. As simple as a solution as this sounds, unfortunately not easy to catch.

Anyway, I had a mismatch of the registered_menu and what was actually what was set up in the admin dashboard.

In function.php I didnt associate 'main_menu' with the 'theme_location'

```
register_nav_menus( 

array(
    'main_menu'   => 'Main Menu', 
    'footer_menu' => 'Footer Menu',
    'comic_menu'  => 'Comic Menu'

)
```

);

Answer (score 0):

upon checking the site that is not working correctly in terms of responsiveness, it seems like a handful of resources just are not loading correctly. I'm 100% sure if the code is identical to your original example that is working, and once you've resolved your sourcing issues, it'll work! Here's a screenshot of the console which is yielding in a bunch of 404's:

[Errors on your example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34OLB.png)

Comment: I was able to resolve. The issue was that the "register_nav_menus" in my functions.php was not the same name as the one in side the admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

console says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Wrong path? Didnt upload the files? :-)